# Segmentation fail for arrays

Tags: c++

I've been scratching my head all day trying to work out why these two arrays produce a segmentation fault.

I can comment out one and the program runs but using both at same time causes it to crash. Could they be overlapping in memory?

I'm clueless, any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

    int y = 3823;
    int x = 10;
    int z = 64;

    double foo[y][x];
    double bar[y][z];

    foo[2][2] = 0;
    bar[2][2] = 2;

    std::cout << foo[2][2] << std::endl;
    std::cout << bar[2][2] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Most likely it is a stack overflow, what compiler and platform? `std::vector` or using a `new` may be a better option.

Comment: The program compiled & ran fine on my computer.  What system & compiler are you using?

Comment: Variable-length arrays are non-standard. Use a `const static` size.

Comment: Im using windows 64bit and compiling using GCC inside codeblocks. I did have the size as const before and still had problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to allocate around 2 megabytes on the stack.  That's a lot of memory.

You should consider some form of dynamic allocation that doesn't allocate these arrays on the stack.

Comment: Ahh thanks so would new be a better idea or std::vector? I'm new to using data sets this large.

Comment: @RichardTSlade Both new and std::vector will do the job.

Comment: @RichardTSlade : Either should work.  One caveat of both is that you'll have to do some additional work to get 2-D array indexing.  For example, if you use `vector< vector< double > >`, I believe you'll have to loop through the first dimension, calling `resize` on all the elements in the 2nd dimension.  Alternately, you can do it with a 1-D `vector`, and do your array indexing as `i + y*j`.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid using them because of those reasons, but it seems I have no choice. Thanks for advice :)

Answer (score 3):

This program does not crash when I run it (with both arrays uncommented).

This program requires more than 2,263,216 bytes of stack just to enter `main`.  It is most likely that your OS does not provide this much stack by default.  You can probably raise the limit, but without knowing what OS you are on, I cannot tell you precisely how.

Comment: Im using 64bit windows pro, the IDE I am using is codeblocks which is 32bit. Does the IDE come in to play here? I have VS installed. Thanks for answer

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about Codeblocks (and very little about Windows in general).  I'd probably search MSDN for "stack size" or "stack limit" if I had this problem.

Comment: Ok thanks might have a look at it if I find std::vector too hard to implement.